# Jquery Modal form login with AJAX - ASP Classic on IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I am having quite a bit of trouble getting a particular login form to work with Jquery using classic asp on IE 9.

On my index.asp page I have the following form:

```
    <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!--#include file="Connections/LogisticsConnection.asp" -->
<%
Dim RS_User
Dim RS_User_cmd
Dim RS_User_numRows

Set RS_User_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
RS_User_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_LogisticsConnection_STRING
RS_User_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UserName, Password FROM Users" 
RS_User_cmd.Prepared = true

Set RS_User = RS_User_cmd.Execute
RS_User_numRows = 0
%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>Training Prioritization</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="img/css/site.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="img/scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="img/scripts/chosen/chosen.css"/>
<script src="img/scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="img/scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="img/scripts/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="img/scripts/siteScript.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="title">Training Prioritization</div>
        <div id="login"><img src="img/loginBtn.png" id="Login-Img">Login</img></div>
    </div><!--END HEADER-->

    <div id="menu">
        <div id = "menuItems">
        <img src="img/editBtn.png" id="Menu-edit">Edit</img>
        <img src="img/saveBtn.png" id="Menu-save">Save</img>
        <img src="img/cancelBtn.png" id="Menu-cancel"/>Cancel</img>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="body">
        <div id="formBody">
            <table id="formTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="Table-Heading-titleGroup">
      <td>Title:</td>
      <td>Project Tracker Number:</td>
      <td>Status:</td>
      <td>Month:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="Form-title"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Form-ptNum"></td>
      <td>      <select id="Form-Dropdown-status"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select></td>
      <td>
      <select id="Form-Dropdown-month"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Table-Heading-requestorGroup">
      <td>Requestor:</td>
      <td>Curriculum/Course:</td>
      <td>Duration:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="Form-requestor"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Form-curriculum"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Form-duration"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Table-Heading-designerGroup">
      <td>Designer:</td>
      <td>Start Date:</td>
      <td>End Date:</td>
      <td>Launch Date:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="Form-designer"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Form-Date-startDate"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Form-Date-endDate"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Form-Date-launchDate"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Table-Heading-project">
      <td>Project Description:</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="Form-Paragraph-projectDescription"></td>
    </tr>
      <tr id="Table-Heading-businessGroup">
      <td>Business Unit</td>
      <td>Legacy Group</td>
      <td>Work Group</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td><select id="Form-Dropdown-businessUnit"><option value="test1">test1</option><option value="test2">test2</option><option value="test3">test3</option></select></td>
      <td><select id="Form-Dropdown-legacyGroup"><option value="test1">test1</option><option value="test2">test2</option><option value="test3">test3</option></select></td>
      <td><select id="Form-Dropdown-workGroup"><option value="test1">test1</option><option value="test2">test2</option><option value="test3">test3</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="Table-Heading-location">
    Location:
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="img/addBtn.png"/><div id="Table-Row-Child-Location">Add Location</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Table-Row-Parent-AddLocation">
    <tr>
    <tr  id="Table-Heading-notes">
    <td>Notes</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="Form-Paragraph-notes"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
      </div>
      <div id="test">
      text here
      </div>
      <form id="Form-Submit" action="verify.asp" method="post">
      <div id="Modal-Menu">
      User Name:<input type="text" id="Modal-Menu-Input-UserName" name="UserName" value="User Name">
      Password:<input type="password" id="Modal-Menu-Input-Password" name="Password" value="Password" >
      </div>
    </form>
    </div><!--END BODY-->
    <div id="footer">
            <div id="footerText" align="center">
        &copy;2015 CenturyLink
            </div>
    </div>
</div><!--END WRAPPER-->

</body>

</html>
<%
RS_User.Close()
Set RS_User = Nothing
%>
```

In my siteScript.js I have the following Jquery:

```
//menu
    $("#login").click(function(){$("#Modal-Menu").dialog("open")});
    $(function(){
        $("#Modal-Menu").dialog(
        {autoOpen:false, 
         modal:true, 
         buttons:{
             Cancel: function(){
                 $("#Modal-Menu").dialog("close");
             },
             'Submit': function(){
                 ajaxSubmit();
             }

         }
         })
    });

    //ajax response
    function ajaxSubmit(){
      $.ajax({
    url: 'verify.asp',
    data: $("#Form-Submit").serialize(),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        },
    error: function(err){
        alert("Error");
        }
  });
  return false;

    };
```

This particular form sends information to verify.asp which has the following code:

```
dim Username
dim Password
Username =Request.Form("UserName")  
Password = Request.Form("Password")
Response.Write(Username)
Response.Write(Password)
```

My issue is that I am unable to get any information from the modal form(which sends infor via POST), and have it properly captured via Request.Form. When I alert out the data, I get the whole verify.html page, but when I look at the response.write for Username and Password, it is blank. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated thanks!

**Edit:** Provided full index.asp document as requested

Comment: What happens with a non-ajax post? Check your outgoing data, either using something like Fiddler or by putting `console.log($("#Form-Submit").serialize());` in you click handler and checking the console for the information. Console.log is much better  than alert.

Comment: Can u please provide your complete code of index.asp

Comment: @ Jon P, when I test using $("#Form-Submit").submit() I'm still not getting anything, also when I use the console.log for $("#Form-Submit").serialize() all I end up getting is "LOG: ". I also Edited question to show full index.asp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out in my index.asp I have:

```
 <form id="Form-Submit" action="verify.asp" method="post">
      <div id="Modal-Menu">
      User Name:<input type="text" id="Modal-Menu-Input-UserName" name="UserName" value="User Name">
      Password:<input type="password" id="Modal-Menu-Input-Password" name="Password" value="Password" >
      </div>
    </form>
```

Note the two form tags that are outside of the "Modal-Menu" div. What it needs to look like is this:

```
  <div id="Modal-Menu">
  <form id="Form-Submit" action="verify.asp" method="post">
  <input type="text"name="UserName" value="User Name"/>
  <input type="password" id="Modal-Menu-Input-Password" name="Password" value="Password"/>
  </form>
  </div>
```

where the form tags are wrapped inside of the "Modal-Menu" div...
Idiocy 1 Hexobolic 0...